# Correct to send JSON object in params?

Tags: api-design, web-api

Maybe I'm being dense, but is it common practice to create an API which requires users to submit GET params as an object? I've encountered one which has me submitting GET requests like...

`http://www.example.com/?ip={keyOne: "ValueOne", keyTwo: "ValueTwo"}`

I find this makes using Postman with the endpoint pretty difficult. Is this a simple pattern I'm not familiar with?

Answer (score 6):

It is pretty weird. Is there something stopping you from using query params?

`http://www.example.com/?keyOne=ValueOne&keyTwo=ValueTwo`

That solves the problem if you only need to send strings or easily parsable values and is the standard way to send multiple simple values directly in the URL of your endpoint.
In Postman, you can then easily edit your query params using the UI since it splits them up nicely.

If you need to receive a complex object or an array of values from the user, you're better off receiving the JSON in the body of your request, since nested keys in your JSON object would be thougher to encode in query params.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using someone else's API so I cannot use query params as you have here. :(

Comment: I see, then it's quite a peculiar choice. One reason might be to be compliant with an old definition of a `GET` request, which disallowed information in the body of the request. See this great answer on StackOverflow if you want to learn more : https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/11292450

Answer (score 0):

That is not a common practice.

Usually, you send JSON in HTTP request body, and if you use the query string, you use just normal URL parameters.

Anything that's more complex than a single-level dictionary, for example if you use nested dictionaries or even arrays, would in most cases make the request object so large that you can't pass it in the limited-size query string. And the query string is already a single-level dictionary so using a JSON dictionary would be just redundant.

In theory, there's nothing preventing URL-encoding JSON objects (assuming the objects are small enough) and sending it as the value of a URL parameter, but that's just bad taste.